# How to display value using Python Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

```
import unittest
import re
import time
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select 

#Navigate to Home page


class VerifyMortgageAmount (unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
    self.driver.get("http://ia.ca")

def test_verify_mortgage_amount (self):
    driver = self.driver

    #Click on Loans in the menu
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='nav-secondaire']/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/span").click()

    #Click on Mortgages
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mortgages").click()

    #Click on Calculate your payments
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Calculate your payments").click()

    #Set Purchase Price value to 500,000
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='PrixProprietePlus']").click()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='PrixProprietePlus']").click()

    #Set Down Payment value to 50,000
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='MiseDeFondPlus']").click()

    #Move to Amortization
    Amortise = Select (driver.find_element_by_id("Amortissement"))

    #Change the term to 15 years
    Amortise.select_by_value("15")

    #Move to Payment frequency
    Frequence = Select (driver.find_element_by_id("FrequenceVersement"))

    #Change it to Weekly
    Frequence.select_by_index(3)

    # Clear Interest rate
    driver.find_element_by_name("TauxInteret").clear()

    # Set Interest rate to 5%
    driver.find_element_by_name("TauxInteret").send_keys("5")

    #Click on Calculate Button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='btn_calculer']").click()

    #Capture amount 
    Amount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='paiement-resultats']").text  

    print (Amount)
    num = re.sub(r'\D', "", Amount)    
    print (num)


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

Using the mentioned script, unable to print "Amount" and "num" value (Giving empty value)

If executed as simple script (without unittest, like below), displaying "Amount" value correctly.

```
import re
import time
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select 

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get("http://ia.ca")

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='nav-secondaire']/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mortgages").click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Calculate your payments").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='PrixProprietePlus']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='PrixProprietePlus']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='MiseDeFondPlus']").click()

Amortise = Select (driver.find_element_by_id("Amortissement"))

Amortise.select_by_value("15")

Frequence = Select (driver.find_element_by_id("FrequenceVersement"))

Frequence.select_by_index(3)

driver.find_element_by_name("TauxInteret").clear()

driver.find_element_by_name("TauxInteret").send_keys("3")

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='btn_calculer']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='btn_calculer']").click()

Amount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='paiement-resultats']").text
print (Amount)
num = re.sub(r'\D', "", Amount)    
print (num)
```

Comment: How do you call the function when executing as a script (not a unit test)

Comment: By giving an empty value do you mean not printing a value at all?

Comment: You do realize I'm trying to help you here right?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your "Calculate" button needs to be clicked twice to work

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-trouver').click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-trouver').click()
```

Also you're making things a little bit harder for yourself by looking everything up by an xpath. Most of the time you just need to look things up by id or class like I've done here. Of course Selenium is very much trial and error. So use your judgement. Not sure why the button needs to be clicked twice. Maybe some javascript?

Comment: After solving the problem, I have to modify the code...Thanks for noticing it.